# Como buscar y modificar una parte especifica de una linea en un fichero de texto

Tags: java, archivo

Estoy programando una aplicación que se asemeje a una biblioteca. El programa guardará autor,titulo,fecha y temática de un libro en un fichero de texto, cada campo separado por comas, de esta manera:

Don Juan Manuel,Conde Lucanor,1331,novela

El usuario, de un libro en concreto, podrá modificar tanto el autor, el titulo, la fecha y la temática. Para ello deberá primero buscar dicho libro, introduciendo su titulo. Mi pregunta es la siguiente.
¿Cómo hago para que mi programa busque, según el nombre introducido, la linea del fichero donde se encuentre, y cuando lo haga, como poder modificar cualquiera de sus campos?
He intentado lo siguiente. Sin resultados:

```
Path miPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("access.txt");
        ArrayList<String> fileContent = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(miPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String[] miLista = new String[fileContent.size() * 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.size(); i++) {
           miLista=fileContent.get(i).split(",");
        }
           //Solo guarda la ultima linea del fichero, mi intencion
           //es guardar en un array todos los elementos separados por
           //, para poder buscarlos recorriendo dicho array 
        Files.write(miPath, fileContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el array "miLista" lo estas sobreescribiendo en cada iteracion del bucle for. Lo que podrias hacer es declarar un ArrayList y ahí guardar el array de strings de cada linea por elemento del arraylist. Te pongo un cacho del código que podría servirte:

```
Path miPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("access.txt");
    ArrayList<String> fileContent = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(miPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    ArrayList<String[]> miArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.size(); i++) {
        //aquí añades a cada elemento de miArray el resultado de separar por "," la línea
        miArray.add(fileContent.get(i).split(","));
    }
```

Si la primera línea es "Don Juan Manuel,Conde Lucanor,1331,novela" en miArray.get(0) tendrías el String[]{"Don Juan Manuel","Conde Lucanor","1331","novela"}
Así tendrías los valores separados y por líneas.

Comment: Se me ha presentado un pequeño problema. Al usar ese trozo de codigo Arrays.toString(miArray.get(0)) me devuelve la linea, pero con "["  al principio de la linea y un "]" al final de la linea.

Comment: Siempre puedes hacer: String línea = Arrays.toString(miArray.get(0)); línea = línea.replace("[","").replace("]",""); en caso de que esos caracteres no se vayan a repetir o: String línea = Arrays.toString(miArray.get(0)); línea =línea.substring(1,línea.length()-1); para eliminar el primer y último carácter.